# Is there a way to run a nodejs script without CLI?

Tags: node.js, node-webkit, electron

I use [nodejs script](https://github.com/websperts/tinypng-cli) to shrink PNG images,but I want to make it's usage more easier(without CLI), so that the designer can shrink the PNG images themselves.
is there a way to transform a nodejs script to a executable file, and the designer can use that sctipt by click?

btw, I also want to make it a GUI with node-webkit or electron. some advice?

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways to provide a gui to end-user for you application

- node-webkit (nw.js)
- electron looks like nice solution, since is manages most of the cross platform problems
- [Web2Executable](https://github.com/jyapayne/Web2Executable) to pack your node-webkit up to standalone .exe for windows
- pack node.js+application into one package with an install system

  - Create desktop shortcut that starts up a localhost server
  - Open up system default browser to specified localhost server which serves your application
- create & upload to npm your package and distribute it from there
- make node.js an executable with [nexec](https://github.com/jaredallard/nexe)
- process stdin and make it an drap&drop files over it and the script starts processing files

personally i would recommend electron since it seems to be well documented and the cross-platform options and ways that it offers are a big plus.

Comment: so the first problem?to transform a nodejs script to a executable file(non GUI, just file)

Comment: well eventually your script will require node.js to be installed , so the user can execute the script, you can skip that requirement by providing installation of node.js along side with your script. You can also create executable .bat or .sh files that call node.js script etc..

Answer (score 0):

I would use Node Webkit (now known as [NW.js](http://nwjs.io)) since it already includes an instance of NodeJS bundled with Chrome. You can easily create executables for different platforms - see [this link](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/How-to-package-and-distribute-your-apps).

NW.js also supports adding Node modules to your application and is really easy to use.